# Python Simulation: Values of Uniform Distribution overshoots the range

Tags: graphing-functions, uniform-distribution, visualization, python

I am trying to plot the uniform distribution. It is supposed to be looking like the following.

[image]

Source:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UC-CBUSQXAo

However, when I try to plot it myself using the python code, it looks like the following.

[image]

Source: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html

It is evident that the range is overshooting many times. Even when I understand that the total area remains 1, why is there an overshoot at the first place? Shouldn't it be between 0 and 1 only?

Please explain.

Comment: the bottom plot is a density histogram, the height of each bar multiplied by the width is equal to the number of times one of the random samples has been within the bar width divided by the total number of random samples.

Comment: 1000 samples is too low to see the distribution. I tried it with 1000000 samples and it looks perfectly uniform.